# How to set delay in seconds to the camera capture on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I want to know if setting a delay in seconds to the camera feed is possible on iOS with Swift.

Let's say I add a 30 second delay to my camera. If I am pointing the camera at a person who is crouching down, and then that person stands up, my camera is not going to show that until those 30 seconds have passed. In other words, it will continue to show the person crouched until that time has passed.

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds extremely difficult. Problem is camera recording is bringing in (most likely) 30 frames a second. So those buffers from 30 seconds ago need to be saved somewhere, and in raw form that is a TON of data so you can't just keep those in memory.

You don't want to write as images because the compression is garbage compared to video.

Perhaps the best way would be to setup your capture, then capture your video in say 10 second segments, save to file, then display those video file segments on an AVPlayer or something. That way it's 'delayed' for the user.

Either way, from my understanding of how things work, the main challenge is what to do with those buffers while waiting to display them. You could potentially stream it somewhere, but then you need a whole backend to support that and then stream it back, seems silly.